# Using class as functions and "global" variables container: bad design?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, class

I spent last months rewriting from scratch a new version of my Python algorithm. One of my goals was to write a perfectly documented code, easy to read and understand for "anyone".

In the same project folder I put a lot of different modules and each module contain a class. I used classes as functions and related variables container, in that way a class contain all the functions with a specific task, for example wrinting on Excel files all the output results of the algorithm.

Here an example:

**Algorithm.py**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from Observer import Observer


def main(hdf_path):

    for hdf_file in os.listdir(hdf_path):

        filename = str(hdf_file.replace('.hdf', '.xlsx'))
        Observer.create_workbook(filename)

        dataframe = pd.read_hdf(hdf_file)
        years_array = dataframe.index.levels[0].values

        for year in years_array:
            year_mean = np.mean(dataframe.loc[year].values)
            Observer.mean_values = np.append(Observer.mean_values, dataframe_mean)

        Observer.export_result()

if __name__ == "main":

    hdf_path = 'bla/bla/bla/'
    main(hdf_path)
```

**Observer.py**

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl


class Observer:

    workbook = None
    workbookname = None
    mean_values = np.array([])


    def create_workbook(filename):

        Observer.workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        Observer.workbookname = filename
        # do other things

    def save_workbook():

        Observer.workbook.save('results_path' + Observer.workbookname)

    def export_results():

        # print Observer.mean_values values in different workbook cells
        # export result on a specific sheet
```

I hope that you can understand from this simple example how do I use class on my project. For every class I define a lot of variables (workbook for example) and I call them from other modules as if they were global variables. In that way I can easily access them from anywhere and I dont need to pass them to functions explicitly, cause I can simply write Classname.varname.

My question is: is it bad design? Will it create some problems or performance slowdown?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is it bad design?

Yes.

> I can simply write Classname.varname.

You are creating a very strong [*coupling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) between classes when you enforce calling `Classname.varname`. The class that access this variable is now strongly coupled with `Classname`. This prevent you from changing the behavior in OOP way by passing different parameters, and will complicate testing of the class - since you will be unable to mock `Classname` and use its mock instead of the "real" class.

This will result in code duplication when you try to run 2 pieces of very similar code in two parts of your app, which only vary in these parameters. You will end up creating two almost identical classes, one using `Workbook` and the other using `Notepad` classes.

And remember the vicious cycle:

```
Hard to test code -> Fear of refactor -> Sloppy code
   ^                                      |
   |                                      |
    ---------------------------------------
```

Using proper objects, with ability to mock them (and [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) is going to guarantee your code is easily testable, and the rest will will follow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll rewrite everything again, trying to use only modules of functions, cause as you problably understood, I don't really need classes. Just curious, does my design afflict the performances in any way? Thank you.